# Use root privilege without password

Tags: command-line, sudo, root

I am on Debian 8 and I am searching for a command in debian to use root privilege without password. I am asking because I already saw it somewhere but can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command is `sudo`.

Add a line such as below into `/etc/sudoers`

```
sigis ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This means user sigis can now run things like the command below without requiring password.

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Comment: I accept this one but I know that I didn't install sudo and I could use root privileges

Comment: Then you have a chicken-and-egg problem. You'll need root privileges to install sudo. Did you install this system yourself? If so, you should have the root password. Also, at least some distros will set up a sudoers file for the person who installed the system; have you just tried to use it? Maybe it already works.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know it's

`sudo -i`

OR

`su`

Comment: `su` does require a password.  And `sudo` does on most systems every 5 minutes, too.

Comment: weird, I must of have my account in sudoers